# Is it good idea to use google translation API for a few words?

Tags: google-translate

I'm making websites for german clients atm and I would like to make it easier for my german colleague and have all texts in my CMS translated automaticly. I would only need to ask the API for the translation once, because I'm saving the translations in database.

So I found out that google charges $20 per 1 M characters, but I would only need a few words translated now and then, something like 1000 a week max.

So I'd like to know, if there are any restrictions, that I need to use some minimum number of translations, or a minimum price for those who don't fully use the api.

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use the translation API for this purpose. When it comes down to GUIs and commands in programs German has its very own expressions which are usually not found in translators. If you have German colleagues, why don't you let them translate it for you. Trust me - it's much better this way. Whenever I find automatically translated GUIs i switch to English to understand what the author actually meant - Yes! It is that bad.

Comment: He is going to check the translations anyway, I just wanted to make it easier for him by having some defaults and if the google api didn't cost almost nothing for this much words, why not use it?

Comment: well - you can safe the money because it is wasted money in my experience. The translation API works better if it has a sentence for context. You'll only have a few words. So: no context => bad translation. I would prefer no translation over a bad translation - or do the translation myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Google Translate for free through [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&q=select%20%2a%20from%20google.translate%20where%20q=%22this%20is%20a%20test%22%20and%20target=%22de%22;)

Comment: This no longer works unfortunately.  It's only a paid service now :(

Answer (score -2):

I think it starts from 1M only, anyway we can't believe the translation because it gets confuse in may cases so just try more tests otherwise it will currupt meaning of the line and sentance, think once again before use.

Comment: Do you mean you have to start paying once you get to 1M?

Comment: No. The FAQ clearly states: Is there any free quota?
No, the Google Translate API is only available as a paid service. Please see Pricing and Support for more details. However we do offer the Google Website Translator gadget, which will translate your website without charge. (https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq?hl=de#pricing)